# How to get the last date from similar records? | Django

Tags: python, sql, django, database, oracle

I have next model. Also below you can see table with data. As you can for example A has 2 close records. The difference only in `change_date` column. I need to take only last date. How to make that with Django ORM?

**models.py:**

```
class Securities(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField()
    bool_value = models.BooleanField()
    code = models.CharField()
    change_date = models.DateField()
    bool_value = models.BooleanField()
```

Lets say I have such **Table**:

```
NAME  | CODE | CHANGE_DATE | BOOL_VALUE
 A    | 8328 | 15.02.2018  |     1
 A    | 8328 | 02.09.2018  |     0
 B    | 8328 | 02.09.2018  |     1
 C    | 8328 | 02.09.2018  |     1
 C    | 8328 | 20.09.2018  |     0
```

I want to filter next result:

```
NAME  | CODE | CHANGE_DATE | BOOL_VALUE
 A    | 8328 | 02.09.2018  |     0
 B    | 8328 | 02.09.2018  |     1
 C    | 8328 | 20.09.2018  |     0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query, via Django ORM, the latest based on `change_date` field, you can use this:

```
Securities.objects.latest('change_date')
```

Comment: I tried your code and as I expected it return only one record which is not what I want. An example of what I want you can see on the post.

Answer (score 1):

I would go like

```
new_securities = Securities.objects.order_by('-CHANGE_DATE').distinct('NAME')
```

explanation you order the table by the CHANGE_DATE the "-" is for reversed
then you distinct the query by name which means will ignore all repetitive names from now on i think it would work

Comment: I use Oracle in my project. Unfortunately I can't use another database. I tried to test your code bit it say that: `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`. Do you have any other ideas, bro? =(

Comment: I tried this but distinct didn't work as I expected: `Securities.objects.filter(code= 8328).order_by('-change_date').values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()`

Comment: The interesting thing is that code above return 36 records if you output each item separately but then I use `count()` it return 33. How even it possible?